# Custom handler isn't displayed in the handler list on the development server

Tags: webforms

Webform custom handler is not showing in DEV server but it works in local.It makes very difficult to save additional information.

```
namespace Drupal\demo_module_dym\Plugin\WebFormHandler;


use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;

/**
 * Form submission handler.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *     id = "demo_module_dym_registration_submission_handler",
 *     label = @Translation("Registration form handler"),
 *     category = @Translation("API"),
 *     description = @Translation("Set User Information on hidden field before submit form."),
 *     cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *     results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 * )
 */
class RegistrationFormHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {


  public function preprocessConfirmation(array &$variables) {
    parent::preprocessConfirmation($variables); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

    if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()){

      $memberid = $form_state->getTemporaryValue('memberid');

      if (isset($memberid)){
        $webform_submission->setElementData('memberid', $memberid);
      }

    }
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state, $webform_submission); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
  }

}
```

Is there way to debug to find the cause webform handler not showing in handler list on sever?

Comment: Have you cleared cache ? What is different between servers ? perhaps a different theme ? any different modules ? start with seeing the differences.  You might want to create the exact duplicate (or as much as possible) of the live server before you can properly debug it.

Comment: Thanks for response, everything is same and clear several times  it didn't work. After, I change the folder name from "WebFormHandler" to "WebformHandler" and add constructor on RegistrationFormHandler. It shows  on handler list but it couldn't add the handler from email/handler setting. Then, I removed the Telephone field and clear the cache and it added on the Form. I get constantly php error message : Notice: Undefined index: description in webform_token_info_alter() (line 396 of modules/contrib/webform/webform.module).
webform_token_info_alter(Array, NULL, NULL) (Line: 539).

Comment: It does not ? does it show any message as to why it does not ? does the logs have any relevant entry ?

Comment: I monitor log it does not shows web form handler message. I used to get  a php error message : Notice: Undefined index: description in webform_token_info_alter() (line 396 of modules/contrib/webform/webform.module).
webform_token_info_alter(Array, NULL, NULL) (Line: 539) I believe it cause by Telephone field

Comment: The error Undefined index: description in webform_token_info_alter() (line 396) may have been fixed in the latest dev release of the Webform module.

Comment: Thanks @jrockowitz, I will check it out.